# Stop processing loop in Pandas group by

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

This pandas function prints a `groupby` by loan id

```
pdf = pd.DataFrame({
    'loan_id': [123, 123, 123, 124, 124],
    'month':  ['202201','202202','202203','202201','202202'],
    'balance':  [ 1200, 1100, 1000, 13000, 11000 ],
    'proba_dft': [0.5, 0.8, 0.1, 0.3, 0.4]
})

pdf.groupby(by="loan_id").apply(lambda x: print(x))

   loan_id   month  balance  proba_dft
0      123  202201     1200        0.5
1      123  202202     1100        0.8
2      123  202203     1000        0.1
   loan_id   month  balance  proba_dft
3      124  202201    13000        0.3
4      124  202202    11000        0.4
```

What I need is the apply to stop processing/printing the loan records if the probability is greater than 0.7, for example the last record of loan_id 123 will not be printed:

```
   loan_id   month  balance  proba_dft
0      123  202201     1200        0.5
1      123  202202     1100        0.8
   loan_id   month  balance  proba_dft
3      124  202201    13000        0.3
4      124  202202    11000        0.4
```

Note that I prefer to stop processing the loop rather than having an `if` condition, as the data is large. How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one by `loc` the rows that are up to the first value above 0.7. The idea is to check where the value is less or equal (`le`) than 0.7, using `cummin` to replace by `False` all the row of the mask `x['proba_dft'].le(0.7)` after the first value above 0.7, then `shift` to keep this last row you want to `print`.

```
(pdf.groupby(by="loan_id")
  .apply(lambda x: print(x.loc[x['proba_dft'].le(0.7).cummin().shift(fill_value=True)]))
)
   loan_id   month  balance  proba_dft
0      123  202201     1200        0.5
1      123  202202     1100        0.8
   loan_id   month  balance  proba_dft
3      124  202201    13000        0.3
4      124  202202    11000        0.4
```

Comment: Ben, can you elaborate what's `x['proba_dft'].le(0.7).cummin()` and why not use a condition like `lt(0.8)`?